# Using Jquery how to run a function endlessly while hovered, then finish on hoveroff

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a dot on a map, that I am trying to pulse (size).  I have the animation working well but I can't resolve two issues:

1. Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
2. when I hover off and then hover back on, it doesn't start again.

Here is my jquery:

```
$('.round-dot').hover(function() {
    var dot = $(this).children('img');
    pulseSucka(dot);
  }, function() {
    var dot = $(this).children('img');
    dot.finish();
  }
);

function pulseSucka(dot){
    $(dot).animate({
        height: '24',
        width: '24',
        paddingLeft: '0',
        paddingTop: '0'
      }, 300, function() {
        // First animate complete
        $(dot).animate({
          height: '18',
            width: '18',
            paddingLeft: '3',
            paddingTop: '3'
          }, 300, function() {
            // Second animate complete
            pulseSucka(dot);
        });
    });
}
```

The dot is 18px (w/h) to start, and I animate the width and padding to make it look like its pulsing.  I am happy with the speed and animate on hover, but when I hover off it doesn't go back to "normal", and when I hover again it does nothing.

Here is a jsFiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/BPKeY/

Comment: `pluseSucka` is calling itself, leading to infinite recursion, and blowing the stack.

Comment: Post html too and make a fiddle

Comment: Good call, doing it now... 2 seconds.

Comment: posted a jsfiddle.  @jonathonReinhart, I know I am but thats really my question: how do I make a function run endlessly until I mouseout?

Comment: Why the downvote?  Not clear enough, happy to fix, trying to learn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can detach the recursive call using window.requestAnimatedFrame.

**WORKING SAMPLE**

http://jsfiddle.net/rnrlabs/788GN/2/

see modifications.

**CODE**

```
$('.round-dot').hover(function() {
    console.log("a");
    var dot = $(this).children('img');
    pulseSucka(dot);
  }, function() {
    var dot = $(this).children('img');
    dot.finish();
  }
);

function pulseSucka(dot){
    $(dot).animate({
        height: '24',
        width: '24',
        paddingLeft: '0',
        paddingTop: '0'
      }, 300, function() {
        // First animate complete
        $(dot).animate({
          height: '18',
            width: '18',
            paddingLeft: '3',
            paddingTop: '3'
          }, 300, function() {
             // Second animate complete
              var f = function() {
                  pulseSucka(dot);
              }
              requestAnimationFrame(f);
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: It doesn't stop pulsing on mouseout

Comment: Works for me.  Stops on hover.

Comment: create your own easing function using this site (http://www.timotheegroleau.com/Flash/experiments/easing_function_generator.htm) and apply it

Comment: That looks like it would smooth out the lot.  No idea how to implement... thanks again

Answer (score 0):

there are various ways to do it, but here's the one that's based on your code. I added another option for your function (state) so it can handle both start and stop of the animation.

http://jsfiddle.net/jlk0417/5GBB5/1/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.round-dot').hover(function () {
        var dot = $('.dot');
        pulseSucka(dot,1);
    }, function () {
        var dot = $('.dot');
        pulseSucka(dot,0);
    });

    function pulseSucka(dot,state) {
        var $el = dot;
        if (!state) {
            $el.stop();
            return;
        }
        $el.animate({
            height: '24',
            width: '24',
            paddingLeft: '0',
            paddingTop: '0'
        }, 300, function () {
            // First animate complete
            $el.stop().animate({
                height: '18',
                width: '18',
                paddingLeft: '3',
                paddingTop: '3'
            }, 300, function () {
                // Second animate complete
                pulseSucka($el,1);
            });
        });
    }
});
```

If you want a pure CSS approach, which I would recommend if you're not serving older browsers,  here's the code

http://jsfiddle.net/jlk0417/5GBB5/

```
@keyframes pulsate {
    0%, 100% {
        transform: scale(1, 1);
    }
    50% {
        transform: scale(1.3, 1.3);
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes pulsate {
    0%, 100% {
        -moz-transform: scale(1, 1);
    }
    50% {
        -moz-transform: scale(1.3, 1.3);
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes pulsate {
    0%, 100% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1, 1);
    }
    50% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.3, 1.3);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks a ton, I didn't realize there was a pure css option.  I like it.  I have to account for ie8+ so I need the js... Many thanks